# Why does my electron window appear solid white instead of transparent, until I click on it from the taskbar?

Tags: electron

I have a window that I make the full size of my screen, it's completely transparent except for a red border:

[image]

Unfortunately, every time I show the window for the first time, the background is completely white, instead of transparent:

[image]

To fix this I have to hover over my app in the taskbar, then click the little windows preview that pops up, then it magically turns transparent and acts like it's supposed to.

[image]

Here is how it is created:

```
const borderWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: screen.width,
    height: screen.height,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    },
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    hasShadow: false,
    parent: timerWindow,
    transparent: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    show: false,
    //fullscreen: true, /*this makes it so the border is around the whole screen, not above the taskbar*/
});

borderWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    console.log('border window ready to show');
})

borderWindow.loadFile('border.htm');

borderWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
```

The ''ready-to-show'' event is definitely triggered before I run `borderWindow.show();` to show it, at which point the new window pops up totally white, until I do the trick mentioned above.

Any advice on how to get around having to do this stupid hack every time I open my program?

Comment: I mocked up your scenario in Electron Fiddle and could not reproduce your issue. The border.htm code might be helpful as I had to guess what you did there (probably not.) What version of Electron?

Comment: I realized my electron version is very out of date, so I probably need to update it before asking